# Label not visible on the window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am using three .xaml windows.MainWindow.xaml gets the contacts of a user from his/her mail account.When user clicks on "See Contacts" button I have called another window which show a label "Getting Contacts.." and when contacts are retrieved the window Disappear and in another window contacts are shown.The problem is that when I click on the button "See Contacts" the 2nd window appear and closed without showing the label "Getting Contacts...".
The code shows a contacts window which is supposed to show contacts.Before calling the function view I called show process.xaml and after that I closed it But label on it is not shown
contacts.xaml.cs

```
        public Contacts(string u,string p)
        {
            process obj = new process();

            InitializeComponent();
            obj.Show();
            view(u, p);//it gets the contacts 
            obj.Close();//window closes here
        }
```

Process.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Practice_project.process"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="process"  Height="100" Width="167"
        WindowStyle="ToolWindow">
    <Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition  Width="1*" ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition  Width="1*" ></ColumnDefinition>

            <ColumnDefinition  Width="1*" ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition  Width="1*" ></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Getting Contacts..." FontSize="20" Margin="0,23,-0.2,0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Height="46" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You are not setting the grid row and column for the label.

Comment: @danish the default values for the row and column is 0. Therefor it is not a problem

Comment: try Setting obj.Owner = this before showing `Process` window...

Comment: I've been trying to get this example to work now for a little bit, and the whole process would be made easier if you tried the MVVM pattern. I'll put up a simple example that is more of a hack MVVM then a good example, but it will get you started. The main problems the UI thread. It's busy processing `view(u,p)` before it gets a chance to draw your label.

Comment: Amol Bavannavar I used  Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => view(u, p), DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle); and l am getting the label.However can please tell why this problem occurs.Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Dispatcher.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your `view` call so that your UI thread becomes available:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => view(u, p), 
                                      DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
```

The reason that you do not see the label is because the work is being made on the UI thread. The UI thread is the thread that is updating your UI. When you create your `Contacts` class you are currently on the UI thread, meaning what you see on the screen will not be updated until the UI thread becomes available to process the objects. That is why when you expect the UI to show your label the work is already complete (because the UI thread executed your `view`method and the `obj.Close` call)

What `Invoke` does is delay the call to `view` until the current Dispatcher (i.e. the UI thread) is `idle`. That gives it time to update the Controls that exist in the Window.

There is a lot of information regarding threading, UI and Dispatcher, probably too much to exist in a single answer here. To read more about threading in WPF you can check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (There's a headline regarding *Handling a Blocking Operation with a Background Thread* that I think might suit you)